# Reading in a .csv that contains vectors (c(x,y)) in R

Tags: r, csv

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I have a bunch (thousands) of .csv files where a few lines contain a vector of numbers instead of a single value that I need to read into a tibble or data frame with the vector as a character for further processing. For example:

```
"col1","col2","col3"
"a",1,integer(0)
"c",c(3,4),5
"e",6,7
```

should end up as

```
  col1   col2        col3     
  <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   
1 a         1          integer(0)  
2 c         c(3,4)     5
3 e         7          7
```

The vector is only ever in "col2" and contains integers. The vector usually contains 2 entries, but it could be more. In reality, there are two columns in the middle that could contain multiple entries, but I know the positions of both.

I can't work out how to read these to R successfully. read.csv or read_csv can't seem to handle them. Is there a way I could read in the files line by line (they're thankfully not long) and eval() the line, maybe, before splitting by commas? I thought about replacing `c(` with `"c(` and `)` with `)"` in bash before reading the files in (and will have to do this to `integer(`.

Alternatively, I've thought of splitting the .csvs in bash into ones that contain "normal" lines and ones that contain the vectors (grep `c(`) but I'm not sure how to then nest 2:length(-1) of the columns back into a vector.

However, I'd definitely prefer a method that was self-contained in R. Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: please edit your Q to show your required output from your sample input. Please don't reply in comments. Good luck.

Comment: Your question doesn't state what you want done with the vector (e.g. NA, first element, 0 etc..)  The read.csv function will bring the column containing c(3,4) in as character vector.

Comment: @andrea, read.csv works better than read_csv, but it pushes the excess to the next row, if that makes sense.

Comment: RonakShah, thanks for catching that! Just a typo.

Answer (score 2):

I typed your example into a csv file, then brought it in with read.csv and specified that column 2 is character. Using gsub I replace the letter c and the open and close parentheses. Then I loop through column 2 to find cases where a comma appears and convert those instances to a list of integers.

```
data <- read.csv("SO question.csv", colClasses = c("character","character","integer"))

data$col2 <- gsub("(c|\\(|\\))","",data$col2)

for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  
  if (grepl(",", data$col2[i]) == TRUE) {
    
    temp <- unlist(strsplit(data$col2[i],","))
    data$col2[i] <- list(as.integer(temp))
    
  } 
}

data
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like both `col2` and `col3` have complex contents.  Assuming that the possible complex contents are `c(...)` and `integer(0)` we enclose both in double quotes and read them in as character converting from character to list in the final line.  (We have used the r'{...}' literal string constant notation introduced in R 4.0 to avoid double backslashes.  Modify as needed if you are using an earlier version of R.)

```
library(dplyr)

DF <- "myfile.csv" %>%
  readLines %>%
  gsub(r'{(c\(.*?\)|integer\(0\))}', r'{"\1"}', .) %>%
  read.csv(text = .) %>%
  mutate(across(2:3, ~ lapply(., function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))))
```

giving:

```
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ col1: chr  "a" "c" "e"
 $ col2:List of 3
  ..$ : num 1
  ..$ : num  3 4
  ..$ : num 6
 $ col3:List of 3
  ..$ : int 
  ..$ : num 5
  ..$ : num 7
```

### Note

We assume the file is as shwon reproducibly below:

```
Lines <- "\"col1\",\"col2\",\"col3\"\n\"a\",1,integer(0)\n\"c\",c(3,4),5\n\"e\",6,7\n"
cat(Lines, file = "myfile.csv")
```

Comment: Oh! I had simplified this for an example. In reality, there are ~20 columns, with two interior ones (with known positions next to one another) that might contain these vectors. This is a useful method but it won't quite work for my purposes. Sorry for not mentioning that necessary detail earlier!

Comment: OK. Have revised using a modified approach.

Comment: I believe `read.csv(text = .)` would work there, no need for `{ read.csv(text = .) }` is it ?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Have removed them.